# TS: Function not accepting generic lambda with base-type

Tags: typescript

I'm struggling to define the types of a resolver of mongoose - and I guess anyone with sufficient knowledge of TypeScript might be able to answer me.

I have two types, both sharing a common base-type. I now have a generic function which should be able to accept either of them. This generic function is now passed into a function specific to one of the two types - this is where I get the conflict.

Here's the URL containing the code:

https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=38&pc=1#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

Here's the code:

```js
interface Document {
  createdAt: Date
}

type Middleware<TArgs> = (
  args: TArgs,
) => void;


// Define a middleware used for many different types - all should be compatible with "Document"
type DocumentCreatedAt = {
  record: Document
}
const createdAtMiddleware: Middleware<
  DocumentCreatedAt
> = (args) => {
  if (args.record) {
    args.record.createdAt = new Date();
  }
};

// Define a function where I register this middleware on document-registries
function registerMiddleware<TArgs>(middleware?: Middleware<TArgs>) : any  {
};

// Register the middleware on a document-type
interface User extends Document {
  username: string
}

registerMiddleware<User>(createdAtMiddleware)

// Register the middleware on another document-type
interface Post extends Document {
  title: string
}
registerMiddleware<Post>(createdAtMiddleware)
```

In my logic, the argument, passed into a function (in my case the function returned by `createdAtMiddleware`) should accept any type having more properties than the one expected within this function. On the other side, a function (now specially referring to `runMiddleware()`) should always receive a type which it is compatible with; which puts me into a dilemma... What would be a proper definition of types without the usage of `any` as type?

**EDIT:** Ok, I should've said this in the beginning: The following definitions cannot be changed by me as they're part of a library I use:

- `type Middleware<TArgs>`
- `registerMiddleware<TArgs>(middleware?: Middleware<TArgs>)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could declare the `DocumentCreatedAt` type to accept the underlying subclass, then you could do something like this:

```js
type DocumentCreatedAt<T extends Document = Document> = {
  record: T
}

async function createdAtMiddleware<T extends Document = Document>(args: DocumentCreatedAt<T>) {
  if (args.record) {
    args.record.createdAt = new Date();
  }
}

// Define a function where I register this middleware on document-registries
function registerMiddleware<TArgs>(middleware?: Middleware<TArgs>) : any  {
};

// Register the middleware on a document-type
interface User extends Document {
  username: string
}

registerMiddleware<DocumentCreatedAt<User>>(createdAtMiddleware)

// Register the middleware on another document-type
interface Post extends Document {
  title: string
}
registerMiddleware<DocumentCreatedAt<Post>>(createdAtMiddleware)
```

Comment: Thanks for taking up the challenge. I forgot to tell you ... I can't change the typings of `type Middleware<TArgs>` or `registerMiddleware<TArgs>(middleware?: Middleware<TArgs>)` - they're both part of a package I use: `graphql-compose-mongoose`

Comment: I don't believe I did change the type definitions of either of those.

Comment: True. Where was my mind ... Thanks for the solution - works as expected!

Answer (score 0):

Here is another approach:

I moved MIddleware generic directly to function

```js
interface Document {
  createdAt: Date
}

type Middleware = <T extends DocumentCreatedAt>(
  args: T,
) => Promise<void>;


// Define a middleware used for many different types - all should be compatible with "Document"
type DocumentCreatedAt = {
  record: Document
}

const createdAtMiddleware: Middleware = async (args) => {
  if (args.record) {
    args.record.createdAt = new Date();
  }
};

// Define a function where I register this middleware on document-registries
function registerMiddleware<T extends Document>(middleware?: <U extends DocumentCreatedAt>(
  args: T & U,
) => Promise<void>): any {
};

// Register the middleware on a document-type
interface User extends Document {
  username: string
}

registerMiddleware<User>(createdAtMiddleware)

// Register the middleware on another document-type
interface Post extends Document {
  title: string
}
registerMiddleware<Post>(createdAtMiddleware)

registerMiddleware<{ age: number }>(createdAtMiddleware) // expected error
```

**UPDATE**
SO, you should do next:

```js
interface Document {
  createdAt: Date
}

type Middleware<TArgs> = (
  args: TArgs,
) => void;


// Define a middleware used for many different types - all should be compatible with "Document"
type DocumentCreatedAt = {
  record: Document
}
const createdAtMiddleware: Middleware<
  DocumentCreatedAt
> = (args) => {
  if (args.record) {
    args.record.createdAt = new Date();
  }
};

// Define a function where I register this middleware on document-registries
function registerMiddleware<TArgs extends DocumentCreatedAt>(middleware?: Middleware<TArgs>) : any  {
};

// Register the middleware on a document-type
interface User extends Document {
  username: string
}

registerMiddleware<User>(createdAtMiddleware)

// Register the middleware on another document-type
interface Post extends Document {
  title: string
}
registerMiddleware<Post>(createdAtMiddleware)
```

You should make sure that your generic argument has `record` property

Comment: Thanks for taking up the challenge. I forgot to tell you ... I can't change the typings of `type Middleware<TArgs>` or `registerMiddleware<TArgs>(middleware?: Middleware<TArgs>)` - they're both part of a package I use: `graphql-compose-mongoose`

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. As far as I've seen, you've changed the definition of the function `registerMiddleware`, which is part of a library I'm using - I cannot change it ... And as of my objection it should also work without changing it ...

Comment: SO you have two functions which are part of the library ? Please tell me which part of the code I allowed to change